# XPath for 0-* child level

Tags: xml, xpath

I have following XML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Export>
    <Folder ID="1004">
        <Object ID="124" Name="NameABC" />
    </Folder>
    <Folder ID="1016">
       <Folder Name="B">
            <Object ID="124" Name="Name1" />
                <Folder Name="A">
                    <Object ID="121244" Name="Name2" />
                    <Object ID="122134" Name="Name12" />
                    <Folder Name="KS">
                        <Object ID="667" Name="Name43" />
                    </Folder>
                </Folder>
        </Folder>
    </Folder>
</Export>
```

Now I need to get all `<Object>`'s under  which have a ID and a NAME.
Sometimes there is 0 Folder under the first Folder with the ID 1016 and sometimes 4.

I need to use a XPath expression. I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Please, add an example of the desired output.

Comment: Sorry, I found the solution myself: /Export/Folder[@ID=1016]/descendant::Object

Comment: Great, so add that as a solution and _accept_ that answer whenever you can at a later date please. Please try not to leaves questions open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//folder[@ID='some_id' and @Name='some_name']/descendant::*`

See:

[image: xpath axes]

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//Object">
   <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/> - <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

will match all `<Object>` elements and output the ID and Name attribute values.

The *descendant* selector is (from the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)) `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`